# Регулярные выражения, отфильтровать только латиницу цифры и определенные знаки?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать регулярку которая бы отфильтровала
Латинские буквы, цифры, символы + и _

```js
const regEx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/; /// Как это розширить ? 

function isValid(str) {
  if (regEx.test(str) === true) {
    console.log("проходит валидация")
  } else {
    console.log("не проходит валидация")
  }
}

isValid("test123+_"); //// true
isValid("test123киРилица<.>/"); //// false
```

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_+]+$/`

Comment: Почему "test123+._" валидный?

Comment: Пардон, да точка там лишняя

Comment: `=== true` там лишнее *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9_+]+$/` можно упростить до `/^[\w+]+$/` — так как `\w` как раз включает латиницу обоих регистров, цифры и нижнее подчёркивание.

```js
const regEx = /^[\w+]+$/;

function isValid(str) {
  if (regEx.test(str) === true) {
    console.log("проходит валидация")
  } else {
    console.log("не проходит валидация")
  }
}

isValid("test123+_"); // true
isValid("test123киРилица<.>/"); // false
```